# What are NFC dynamic tags and how are they different from encrypted and unencrypted NFC tags? Are these further categorizations of Tag Types 1-4?

Tags: mobile, nfc

I am able to find results with NFC Type 1, Type 2 tags, etc. but I can't find any information on NFC dynamic tags, encrypted, and unencrypted NFC tags.

Can anyone please explain here and provide me with a relevant link of the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony has a product [FeliCa Plug](http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/products/RC-S801_802.html) that they call a "dynamic tag". I am not aware of any other products that have similar functionality.

Some NFC tags offer, next to NFC Forum Type 1/2/3/4 Tag functionality, other functionality such as authentication and encrypted communication. However, the specifics of such functionality can be considered proprietary, as it is not standardized. Examples:

- NXP MIFARE Ultralight C: Type 2 Tag compatible, offers also password protection
- Sony FeliCa: Type 3 Tag compatible, offers also authentication and encryption
- NXP DESFire: Type 4 Tag compatible, offers also authentication and encryption

Details of such tags are usually only available under NDA, though.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic NFC tag is also known as dual interface tag, at the same time there is I2C and wireless support. Such as TI's RF430CL330H, you can modify the tag with I2C, such as Arduino board. Reference https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/dnfc-tag-nfc-that-interacts-with-microcontroller#/